# hyperlink around flash banner

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flash

The hyperlink is not coming in Chrome and Firefox (in firefox link is opening if I click but pointer does not show clickable). I am trying with this:

```
<a href="http://www.teamrustic.com/" target="_blank"> 
    <embed class="ads" 
           style="margin:0px;border:0px;" 
           src="swf/flash_banner.swf"
           width="315" height="100" wmode="opaque">
    </embed>
</a>​
```

tried with CSS `.ads{cursor : pointer;}`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the flash is trapping the click event and not filtering it through the DOM in some browsers. There is no specific fix for this.

There are two workarounds that I know of:

1. Add code to your swf file which deals with the click and opens the appropriate URL
2. Place a 'shim' invisible link on top of the flash which captures the click and links appropriately - note you can only have 1 of these over your flash file, so if you need two links in the flash file, it won't work.

Example of #2:

```
<div id="flashContainer">
    <a id="shim" href="mylink.aspx">&nbsp;</a>
    <div id="flash">
        <embed class="ads" src="swf/flash_banner.swf" width="315" height="100" wmode="opaque"></embed>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#flashContainer {
    position: relative;
}
#flash { 
    z-index: 5;
}
#shim {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 315px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

**Updated**

Example of #2 using a div, with jQuery hooking up the click event:

```
<div id="flashContainer">
    <div id="shim"></div>
    <div id="flash">
        <embed class="ads" src="swf/flash_banner.swf" width="315" height="100" wmode="opaque"></embed>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#flashContainer {
    position: relative;
}
#flash { 
    z-index: 5;
}
#shim {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 315px;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: hand; cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

```javascript
$("#shim").click(function() {
    window.location.assign("mylink.aspx");
});
```

Comment: Why not a link instead of a div "capturing the click appropriately" - otherwise I agree with your solution

Comment: A link would work just as well too, I suppose, so long as it was `display: block` and contained an `nbsp;`

Comment: @mikevoermans In fact, I think the link would be more elegant as it removes the need for js - answer edited I've not tested it but it should work too. Thanks :)

Comment: well this would be better without javascript. let me try and come back.

Comment: this is fine for chrome and firefox, but I need to support the evil IE . could you revert once to the javascript solution ?

Comment: @tusar no problem - I've added it back in

Comment: with `window.location.assign("mylink.aspx");` also it is not opening in IE.

Comment: In that case I don't think this is possible - your only option is to include the link in the `swf` itself.

Comment: yeah, I need to revert back to them as I dont develop flash. but there will be problem when I need to insert it for dynamic links. Actually it is a content management website, so nothing is fixed.